# Editing CSV row with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to edit a single row in a csv file. I've got a CSV file that looks like the bellow:

TYPE|FOOD TYPE|FEED TIME|WASH TIME

LION|MEAT|4H|1D

FOX|MEAT|5H|3D

HEN|SEED|6H|6D

FISH|PLANTS|7H|99D

I want to edit the row based on its TYPE. If the user wants to edit the FOX row they only need to type FOX when prompted. The issue I'm facing is that the I can't edit the file for some reason.

My code is bellow, I open the existing db, find the row in question, change it, then write it, along with the other rows, into a temp file that I can overwrite the original with.

```
def edit_animal_entry(type):
with open(animal_csv, 'r') as file_read:
    reader = csv.reader(file_read, delimiter="|")

with open(temp, 'w') as file_write:
    writer = csv.writer(file_write)
    for row in reader:
        print(f"{' | '.join(row)}")
        if row[0] == type:
            animal_type, animal_food, animal_feed, animal_wash = animal_inputs()
            writer.writerow([animal_type, animal_food, (animal_feed+"H"), (animal_wash+"D")])
        else:
            writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(temp, animal_csv)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've 'closed' the read file by stopping the `with` block before reading anything out of it. Therefore you aren't looping over your input file. A solution would be to open the input and the output file in the same with statement:

```
def edit_animal_entry(type):
  with open(animal_csv, 'r') as file_read, open(temp, 'w') as file_write:
      reader = csv.reader(file_read, delimiter="|")
      writer = csv.writer(file_write)
      for row in reader:
          print(f"{' | '.join(row)}")
          if row[0] == type:
              animal_type, animal_food, animal_feed, animal_wash = animal_inputs()
              writer.writerow([animal_type, animal_food, (animal_feed+"H"), (animal_wash+"D")])
          else:
              writer.writerow(row)

  shutil.move(temp, animal_csv)
```